# Showing that the perimeter of a circle is $2\pi r$. Isn't this a definition?

Tags: calculus

Today, I ran into a calculus class and the professor was calculating the perimeter of a circle using arc lenghts. Even though they seemed to be on the right track, there is a problem:

They are using *$\sin x$* and *$\cos x$* functions, which are actually defined using the perimeter of a circle, aren't they? So, in my opinion, that was not a real proof since they were using what they want to show.

Or am I missing something? Was that a real proof?

**Edit:** I don't know but most probably they defined $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ in the usual way, because it was a calculus class.

Comment: $\sin$ and $\cos $ can be defined in loads of ways.

Comment: You can use perimeter $=2 \pi r$ to define $\pi$.  In that case, you have to prove $\sin$ and $\cos$ have the properties you want.  Or you can define $\sin$ and $\cos$ from (for example) their series, in which case you want this proof.  There are similar issues with $\exp$ and $\ln$.  You have to start somewhere, then prove all the other definitions follow from the one you chose.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin x$ and $\cos x$ can be defined using the unit circle, but there are alternate definitions. For example, $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ can be defined as:

$$\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

and

$$\cos x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

which are just their Taylor Series representations.